# Play Multiple sounds in the same time in react native with any Audio Player for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, audio, avaudioplayer

my problem is I have multiple sounds that need to play simultaneously , exactly in the same time without any delay , basically I develop with react native but there is any solution with it so I decided to search for a native one , with Swift or Objective C , I read about multiple player in iOS like AvAudioPlayer and AvAudioPlayerNode , but I don't reach my goal always there is a delay of milliseconds , I think always the delay come from the loop , I mean from the loop iterations , and maybe because iOS don't have support for multithreading specially with the players that I used , so what I want is method like Array.Play() where we start playing all the array audio files exactly in the same time ,

this what I tried with AvAudioPlayer :

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(playMultiple:(NSArray *)keys withCallback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(audioSessionChangeObserver:)
                                                 name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification
                                               object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(audioSessionChangeObserver:)
                                                 name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                               object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];
    
    NSMutableArray *players = [NSMutableArray array];
    

        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            AVAudioPlayer *player = [self playerForKey:key];
            if (player) {
                [players addObject:player];
            }
        }

    
    if (players.count > 0) {
        // Create a group for audio mixing
        AVAudioPlayer *groupPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
        [groupPlayer prepareToPlay];
        
        for (AVAudioPlayer *player in players) {
               [player play];
           }
        
      
        };
    
}
```

and this what I see with AVAudioEngine

```
let engine = AVAudioEngine()
var playerNodes: [AVAudioPlayerNode] = []


for playerNode in playerNodes {
    engine.connect(playerNode, to: mixer, format: nil)
}


try! engine.start()

// Start playing all the sounds simultaneously
for playerNode in playerNodes {
    playerNode.play()
}
```

I already searched all the internet ,I hope you can help with any useful link or solution or Audio Engine ,

thank you in advance